# RandomReal behavior in Block environment

Tags: evaluation, localization

I ran into an unexpected behavior of RandomReal function inside the Block environment.
If I simplify my problem: I wanted to use two random local variables, such that the second one would be less that the first one. I initialized both of them inside the brackets like this:

```
ClearAll[x, y]
Block[
 {x = RandomReal[10], y = RandomReal[x], z = RandomReal[y]},
 Print[x]; Print[y]; Print[z]; Print[x]; Print[y]; Print[z]
 ]
```

I got the following result:

```
4.84284
0.0453673
1.63126
4.84284
2.68987
1.1345
```

and a warning:

```
RandomReal::unifr: The endpoints specified by x for the endpoints of the uniform distribution range are not real valued. >>
RandomReal::unifr: The endpoints specified by y for the endpoints of the uniform distribution range are not real valued. >>
```

Value of x seems to be the same all the time, but the values of y and z change. Note that the value of y changes even if the variable is not called explicitly (value of z in the third line is greater than the value of y in the second line), but the value of x never changes - I don't want to generalize too soon, but I executed upper code several times and the values of y and z were never greater than the value of x.

Since I wanted the values of x,y and z to be fixed, I canged the code into:

```
ClearAll[x, y]
Block[
 {x, y, z},
 x = RandomReal[10]; y = RandomReal[x]; z = RandomReal[y];
 Print[x]; Print[y]; Print[z]; Print[x]; Print[y]; Print[z]
 ]
```

and got wanted output:

```
8.72751
2.74445
0.630739
8.72751
2.74445
0.630739
```

Can someone please explain how Block works? I can't explain the behavior of this construct in the first case I described. I read the documentation but didn't find the answer there - probably missed something?

Thanks,
Špela

Comment: Covered [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs) in grueling detail...

Comment: In short, you do `Block[{x=1,y=x},{x,y}]` this won't work, because you cannot *use* `x` in the initialization list where it is defined.

Comment: To add to what @halirutan said, the reason for this is that initialization list code picks values from surrounding (more global) environment, so the r.h.s. of some variable initialization can not use the newly localized values of variables standing prior to this one, in the initialization list. In the body of `Block`, you use `CompoundExpression`, which does compute things one by one, so by the time you do the next assignment, previous variables have their values all right, so then the result is different. This is not specific to `Block`, using `Module` would have the same issue here.

Comment: @rasher It just came to my mind that while we do have a post on the *uses* of scoping constructs, we don't really have one on *mechanics* of them, and it might be useful to have one (we do have this info scattered over a number of different threads).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: Agreed, though the pointers to the tutorials in the referenced OP cover the mechanics about as well as can be done, I think. Maybe a community wiki thingy with a condensation of those?

Comment: @rasher Yep, something like that, plus some notes and remarks from our collective experiences. I do agree that the docs do a very good job in this department, overall - but not everyone knows where to read about what.

Comment: @halirutan: I executed the code you suggested and it works.  It doesn't work with Module - this is why I used Block in the first place.

Comment: @rasher: thanks for the link, it appears to be very useful.

Comment: @Spela: Glad you found link useful. As to your reply to *halirutan*: it *appears* to work, but what's happening under the covers is probably not what you think. Try, e.g. `Block[{a=1,b=a+2},Information[b]]` and observe result, then e.g. `a = 10; b = 20; Block[{a = 1, b = a + 2}, Information[b]]` and compare....

Comment: @Spela I'm sorry, my comment was too sloppy. It wasn't meant as `Block`  example. It was just *something like this doesn't work* (as you might expect it). As @rasher already pointed out, it only *seems* to work. Read the comment of Leonid and the link of rasher carefully and you shortly see that the initialization list of `Block`/`Module` is different from e.g. an *initialization section* in Java or C.